# Dead Google search submit button

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome

The website I'm working on

http://bit.ly/aokA4I

has a Google custom search form on the top right. The blue submit button works

**-- OK** on FF, Safari, Chrome on Mac (style OK).

**-- OK** on IE7, IE8 (style OK).

**-- BUT DOESN'T WORK on FF, Chrome on Windows!!** (the style also gets messed up!)

Does this make any sense?

This Google search button is styled and structured identical to another one in the sidebar for Feedburner subscriptions -- funny thing, the Feedburner button works on all browsers and OS.

Any pointers? Do you think it's the Google search JS that is screwing things up?

Thanks!

Comment: In what way does it fail to work?

Comment: when you hover you get no pointer cursor -- and clicking has no effect  -- but these things ONLY happen on FF, Chrome ON WINDOWS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using an `<input type="submit" />` instead of a `<button>` would sort things out.

Answer (score 0):

that code won't work, you should use input type="button" instead of this. and also add a onclick="functionToExecute".